# My selinium with java build is sucess in jenkins but Browser not open

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, testing, automated-tests

I have tried
There is a checkbox under the Log On tab in the properties window for a Windows service that is called "Allow service to interact with desktop." If you're trying to check that box programmatically, you need to specify the SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS flag when you create your service using the CreateService API. (See MSDN).
Please provide solution if anyone knows.